# Getting NumberFormatException after splitting string

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I've written a string to file which consists of file name and its length. But when I extract that string from file and then split it using "space" delimiter and then try to get number (which is file length), it gives NumberFormatException.Can anyone help??

```
import java.io.*;
public class DemoReadFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,NumberFormatException {
        byte[]b=new byte[100];int pos=0;byte[]data;
        System.arraycopy("dest.txt".getBytes(), 0, b, 0, "dest.txt".length());

        pos+="dest.txt".length()+1;
        System.arraycopy(" ".getBytes(),0,b,pos," ".length());//1 byte here
        pos+=1;
        System.arraycopy("11".getBytes(), 0, b, pos, 2);
        pos+=2;
        System.arraycopy("\n".getBytes(), 0, b, pos, "\n".length());
        pos+="\n".length();//1 byte here
        pos+=37;
        System.arraycopy("Hello World".getBytes(), 0, b, pos, "Hello World".length());
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File("DemoRead.txt"));
        fos.write(b);
        fos.close();
        //FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File("DemoRead.txt"));
        byte[]rhead=new byte[50];
        RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile(new File("DemoRead.txt"),"rw");
        raf.seek(0);
        raf.readFully(rhead);
        String[] tok=new String(rhead).split(" ");
        for(String t:tok)
            System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println(tok[1]);
        raf.seek(50);
        Integer i=new Integer(tok[1]);
        int len=Integer.parseInt(tok[1]);
        data=new byte[i];
        raf.readFully(data);
        //System.out.println("Data is: "+new String(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to print `new String(rhead)` to see what's inside it?

Comment: your tok[1] include the end of the line you should get rid of this. (\n) use String[] tok=new String(rhead).split("\\s+");

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] tok=new String(rhead).split("[ \t\n]");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20138003)

Comment: it does solve the problem. Just try executing his code with this change. It works.